# How can I set values in a 2D array from keyboard

Tags: c#, arrays

I´m working on some codes in C# for school. But there is this exercise that is huge headache.

This is it: I have to develope a code that allows the user to set a value (put in an x) for a 2D array (5x5) from the keyboard. This means that when running the program the user should be able to set one value inside the array, something like "I wana set an "x" in 2,5 and 3,1". I just have no clue how to do that. it´s been already two weeks but i can´t figure it out.

This is what i have so far (updated, thnx to all, specially BradleyDotNET for support):

```
int[,] data = new int[5, 5]; 

    public void load()
    {
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split('=');
        string[] coordinates = input[0].Split(',');

        int[] intCoordinates = coordinates.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

        data[intCoordinates[0]][intCoordinates[1]] = int.Parse(input[1]);  
    }

    public void view()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Matrix created is:");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(data);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program objeto = new Program();
        objeto.load();
        objeto.view();   

        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.Clear();
```

I also have to add a feature to let the user add as many "x" to the matriz as he wants, but im planning to do that with a "switch".

So, How do you set values inside the 2d array from keyboard?

Update: The mistake i get here is in line 10, inside "data". It says "Incorrect index number inside []. 2 was expected"

Comment: Prompt the user for the <row,col> coordinates, and the value.  Index the matrix with those values.

Comment: Break it into smaller problems. Read a value from keyboard. Read two values from keyboard. Check values are in range. Set value of array based on input. Which step do you have difficulty with?

Comment: It´d be the code for setting value from keyboard, I treid with something like "SetValue[a,b]=int.Parse(Console.Readline());" previously declaring "a" and "b", but didn´t work. Im quite sure there has to be a better way, or maybe im missing something

Comment: _"but didn´t work"_ does not work as a problem report. Post code you tried with full error details.

Comment: Aside: don't declare `i,j` at the class level. Make them part of the smallest piece of code possible: `for(int i = 0; ...)`

Comment: Yeah, you are right about the "i" and "j", actually if i take them out the code is still working

Comment: Thank you Henk for your answer. I´d post the error i got if i had something to post, but i have no clue how to do the set in value stuff T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the format the input, so I"ll make one up. If the input was "2,4=10" (meaning set element[2][4] to 10), the code would be:

```
string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split('=');
string[] coordinates = input[0].Split(',');

int[] intCoordinates = coordinates.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

matrix[intCoordinates [0]][intCoordinates [1]] = int.Parse(input[1]);
```

This code has a few problems with it, there is no range validation and if the user enters anything other than an int, it will throw. I'll leave those as an exercise to you, but feel free to ask if you run into trouble.

To explain, we use `Console.ReadLine` to get a whole line of input. Then we break it on the '=' character to get our coordinates and desired value. We then split the coordinates on ',' to get the different indices.

You can't use strings as array indices, so we call `Select` to invoke the int.Parse() function on each string, returning us a new array of ints.

Finally, we use the parsed indices to index into `matrix` and set it to the parsed value from the input.

Comment: Bradley, thanks for your time, i added your code and i got as follows Error #1 "No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' en 'int[]'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)" 
Error #2 "El nombre 'data' no existe en el contexto actual" (sorry to add it in spanish, thats the version i got and i wanted to post exactly what i got). Regrding #1, i had never seen such message, so dont know exaclty what to do, and about #2 i think i have to set and "int data();" somewhere, i did it but keep getting the message.

Comment: Ummm... can you try to translate? I don't understand spanish. As far number one, I have updated my code to what I *think* will fix it.

Comment: For number two, I made up a variable name. Use "matrix" instead of "data" (edited to fix this)

Comment: Well, numer 1 would be something like "Cannot turn "System.Collections:generic:IEnumerable<int> into int[], there is already one explicit conversion. Check if one conversion is missing"

Comment: Using ToArray() should fix that one.

Comment: Maybe it´s dumb to ask but, how do you do that? Sorry, it´s been only one month since i started learning programming T-T

Comment: Check my third line, I appended "ToArray" to it to convert the IEnumerable into an array.

Comment: And about #2 i changed the names as you said and got fixed but i got a new one "Incorrect index number inside [], 2 was expected". As it seems it´s about something inside data

Comment: I added the ToArray() where you post it, and got fixed! Yay!

Comment: Well, im done with other chores and back to work with the code. I just updated it above. I´m getting this error: "Index number incorrect inside []; 2 was expected" in line 10 (data[intCoordinates[0]][intCoordinates[1]] = int.Parse(input[1]);).   Trying stuff I modified the first intCoordinates to [0,1] and the mistake changed from "2 was exptected" to "1 was expected". Now im stuck here. Need more advice   >_<u

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you.

```
 public void load()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {                
            for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter value for {0},{1}", i, j);
                matrix[i,j]= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
```

BTW, in your `view` method start the loop from `0 to 4`

Comment: This is correct for populating the entire array, but not for setting a single value (which it looks like the question was about, but perhaps I read it incorrectly).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I made assumption based on the view method

Comment: Well, actually you have to set in one value see the whole matrix     >-<, thats why the "view" loads the complete matrix

Comment: I fixed the loop as suggested, now im going to try it. Thx.